# How do I link two input fields of type date?

Tags: forms, laravel, date, input

I have two input fields:
`<input name="check_in" type="date" class="checkin">` and
`<input name="check_out" type="date" class="checkout"`
I want to link them so when i pick a date from `check_in` field i can only pick the current day or a later day (earlier days disabled). After that I have to choose a day in the `check_out` field and i can only choose the day chosen in `check_in` or a later day (Other days have to be disabled)

I have been trying several solutions and code snippets but with no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap datepicker, then you can assign the start date of `check_out` to the date on `check_in`. Something like

```
$('.checkin').datepicker({
    startDate: 'd' //this means today
});

$('.checkout').datepicker({
    startDate: $('.checkin').val(); //Not sure of this but you get the idea
});
```

Alternative, just use the daterage option, which has everything implemented already:

```
<div class="input-group input-daterange">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-05">
    <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-19">
</div>
```

And Javascript that goes with

```
$('.input-daterange input').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker('clearDates');
});
```

More here: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#date-range

This will give you exactly what you need out of the box.

Comment: there is no boostrap in the question.